# Cannot delete an image file that is shown in a listview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview, filelock

In my listview I show thumbnails of small images in a certain folder. I setup the listview as follows:

```
var imageList = new ImageList();
foreach (var fileInfo in dir.GetFiles())
{
    try
    {
        var image = Image.FromFile(fileInfo.FullName);
        imageList.Images.Add(image);
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("error");
    }
}

listView.View = View.LargeIcon;
imageList.ImageSize = new Size(64, 64);
listView.LargeImageList = imageList;

for (int j = 0; j < imageList.Images.Count; j++)
{
    var item = new ListViewItem {ImageIndex = j, Text = "blabla"};
    listView.Items.Add(item);
}
```

The user can rightclick on an image in the listview to remove it. I remove it from the listview and then I want to delete this image from the folder. Now I get the error that the file is in use. Of course this is logical since the imagelist is using the file.

I tried to first remove the image from the imagelist, but I keep on having the file lock.

Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<strike>You need to load the file into a MemoryStream, like this:</strike>

```
var image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(fileInfo.FullName)));
```

This way, the file will only be read once, and will not remain locked.

### EDIT

You're loading the images into an ImageList.
Since the ImageList makes copies of its images, you should simply dispose the originals right away, like this:

```
using (var image = Image.FromFile(fileInfo.FullName))
    imageList.Images.Add(image);
```

Comment: @Enrico: this is very wasteful of machine resources.  You simply forgot to call image.Dispose() after adding it to the ImageList.

Comment: @Hans: Does the `ImageList` make a copy of the image?

Comment: It clones the bitmap to match the size and color depth of the ImageList.

Answer (score 1):

The image will need to be disposed of before it will unlock the file. Try calling `Dispose` on the image object after you remove it from the image list.

So long as you have a reference to the image object and the GC hasn't collected it, it will keep the lock. Calling `Dispose` should force it to give up its handle and cause the file to be unlocked.

You also have to make sure that the app didn't `CopyHandle` or otherwise get a second reference to the image resource before doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Use `GetThumbnailImage` and then dispose image:

```
var image = Image.FromFile(fileN);

Image imgThumb = image.GetThumbnailImage(100, 100, null, new IntPtr());

imageList1.Images.Add(imgThumb);

image.Dispose();

listView1.LargeImageList = imageList1;
```

Now you can delete the file:

```
File.Delete(FileN);
```